# Upgrading from 16LTS to 18LTS broke Samba AD DC

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, samba

I have a windows server as a member of my Samba DC, but after upgrading to latest 18LTS, it says no logon servers available.
I can browse it's samba shares (triggering auth), but no longer log into RDP with my domain creds.
Anything happen in the latest samba? Maybe i need to manually migrate some settings/users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out systemd added a DNS Stub listener by default and Samba just kept running without complaining even though it's builtin DNS couldn't run.

I turned off the systemd dnsstub listener and restarted Samba. Bingo.